# Access CustomProperties set using office365 JS APIs from EWS or REST API

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I have an office 365 mail app that stores a value in a custom property before the item is saved. When the item is saved I want to access this property using a server-side application. [Reading through the custom properties documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161021.aspx) tells me I can't access custom properties created using the JS API using any other service like EWS since these are not MAPI properties. Are there any workarounds ? Is it possible to access these using REST APIs ?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it is documented where they are stored and in what format. The [[MS-OXCEXT]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968549(v=exchg.80).aspx) specification provides the specifics. Basically the values are stored as a JSON dictionary in a custom property on the item. You should be able to use EWS to read that custom property as an `ExtendedProperty`.

**UPDATE:** After discussing with folks internally, I should disclaim that this isn't a supported method as MrPiao indicated. As stated, the storage design could change, which would break your app if you depend on the current design. The concern is that I don't want to lead you down a path that eventually becomes unworkable :). If you can describe what your end goal is, perhaps we can suggest a more durable solution.

Comment: Thanks @jason-johnston. This was really helpful, I was able to achieve what I wanted. My next goal is to access these properties from a resource mailbox who is an attendee of the original meeting. But this didn't work.  I was successful accessing a public_string saved using EWS this way. Am I onto a blind alley here ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those properties will only exist on the user's copy that's using your mail app. The resource's copy won't have those properties.

Comment: Is this to do with it being a resource mailbox ? I have seen public strings carry when you send the meeting request if the attendee is internal. can we get around this issue by using a user-mailbox ?

Comment: @JasonJohnston in our scenario we need access to some custom properties because we need to track a 'sent item' while it is composed. Precisely, we add a custom property to the draft email and at the same time we subscribe to the 'sentitems' push notification with Outlook REST API. In web hook we read this custom properties to get access to the info inserted at writing time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Guid PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS = new Guid("00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"); ////PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS' GUID
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS, "cecp-{your add-in manifest id}", MapiPropertyType.String);
PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet() { extendedPropertyDefinition };

message.Load(psPropSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Properties are definitely meant to be created and accessed only by Apps for Outlook APIs. **However**, this property has to get stored somewhere - and that's on the item. I'm fairly certain that if you made a GetItem call and enumerated every property on the item, you'll be able to access the custom props.

What's important to note is that this is most definitely an **unsupported scenario**. The design may change in the future, and this scenario may break. I would definitely not access custom properties outside a Mail App in a production setting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to access these properties using the link in Jason's answer. Why would you call in an **unsupported scenario**. if MSFT want to change where you store these values, you would have to come up with a way to migrate existing data on all office 365 apps and mailboxes which I think is not easy to do.  Aren't we pretty safe here?

Comment: I'm going to defer to my colleague Jason (answered above). He has more information for you.