# Outlook web add-in How to save info to customer properties in EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Using Office.js API we can easily save extra info to the `CustomProperties` object via `customProps.set`. The information is specific to the mail item.

The is the doc [Save to custom properties using office.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=office-js)

Can I achieve the same thing using `EWS` API?

I tried [Creating custom extended properties by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633654(v%3Dexchg.80)) But whatever info saved via this method I cannot retrieve it using Office.js 's `customProps.get`.

The User case is that my add-in will save the email body and its attachments binary to the external application. Upon finish the client side will use Office.js 's `customProps.set` to save the success info to the server, and if you click the same email next time the app will use `customProps.get` to show you the email has been saved. But if during the lengthy save process(maybe save a big attachment, the user close the task pane, before the `customProps.set` is executed, the `customProps.set` will simply not fire because the browser environment (task pane) is closed. So I need to implement this using EWS's API.

My C# code:

```
Guid PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS = new Guid("a8e14732-37cf-4a46-b69f-1111111111");//add-in manifest id

        ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition =
        new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS, "Expiration Date", MapiPropertyType.String);
        Email.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString());
        Email.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);//'The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.'
```

JS Code:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {
                var customProps = asyncResult.value;
                console.log(customProps);
                console.log(customProps.get('Expiration Date')); //undefined
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that but these type of properties follow a specific format because they are application specific. This is documented in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968549(v=exchg.80).aspx.  They are a named property within the PS_PUBLIC_STRING propset of type String. The property name of the property is prefixed with cecp- and rest of the property name is the GUID of your Mail Apps as defined in the application's manifest Id . The best way to see this is look at item where you have set the property in a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi where you can see the property (easy to identify with the Cecp prefix) and the format for the value (JSON)

Edit Code example

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "cecp-a8e14732-37cf-4a46-b69f-1111111111", MapiPropertyType.String);
        Email.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, "{\"Expiration Date\":\"blah\"}");
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a bit of code sample? Both saving it using EWS and retrieve it using Office.js? I do not find the doc very straightforward...

Comment: added example based on what you provided, the Get should work okay but use a MAPI editor and double check everything its really easy and a skill you should try to learn

Comment: I did spot the named property and the JSON value using OutlookSpy, but my original code does not work, because the access token return from Office.js does not allow me to update the email...

Comment: The token provided by Office.js can be used only for the methods documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services. Answer suggested by @GlenScales works but we do not recommend editing the properties directly on the server. You can stamp the custom property early and save the information in your server as a workaround.

Comment: how to get customProps via EWS from JS. The code below does not work
<t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="Expiration Date" PropertyType="String"/>'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code to save info to extended custom properties that can be read using `Office.js`.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("{email}", "{password}");

Guid PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS = new Guid("00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"); //PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS' GUID
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition =
            new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS, "cecp-{add-in manifest id}", MapiPropertyType.String);
Email.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, {JSON});

Email.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

It works. Note that to be able to perform this "write" action, I need to change the authentication from `OAUTH` to `basic`(email+password). And I do not think this is a robust way and it should not be recommend for production environment.
[Why not recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187358/access-customproperties-set-using-office365-js-apis-from-ews-or-rest-api)

Comment: The token provided by Office.js can be used only for the methods documented here: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services. You can refer this link to find ways to authenticate to EWS directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange.