# Access Custompropertie set by Office.js from EWS

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office-js

I have made a Outlook Addin Angular8 Application using Office.js to interact with Outlook.

Everything works fine, the Addin works fine and stores a CustomPropertie to the Mailitem which can be read after reopening the Mailitem.
In this Implementation this is a simple hashmap.

```
this.customPropertiesContainer.set('lvAppointmentServiceId', this.selfiId);
this.customPropertiesContainer.saveAsync();
```

Now I want to read the Propertie in another Application using EWS to get the Mail Item.
Here the Implementation is very complex.

```
private PropertySet getPropertySetKnown() {
    PropertySet propertySet = null;
    try {
        propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, getExtendedPropertyDefinition());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return propertySet;
}

private ExtendedPropertyDefinition getExtendedPropertyDefinition() throws Exception {
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
            DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, CATERING_JIRA_ID, MapiPropertyType.String);
    return extendedPropertyDefinition;
}
```

---

Item boundItem = Item.bind(this.exchangeService, appointmentId, getPropertySetKnown());
jiraCateringId = boundItem.getExtendedProperties().getItems().stream()
.filter(property -> property.getPropertyDefinition().getName().equals(CATERING_JIRA_ID)).findFirst()
.orElse(null);

---

Does anyone know in which DefaultExtendedPropertySet the Propertie could be found set by Office.js ?
Is there a way to get all Propertis using EWS with no need to define an own Definition?

Is there any Debug Tool in Outlook / Exchange to see the Customproperties in an Item?

Comment: I'd start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056097/outlook-web-add-in-how-to-save-info-to-customer-properties-in-ews it should answer this

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Glen Scales [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056097/outlook-web-add-in-how-to-save-info-to-customer-properties-in-ews) should answer your question.
Also you can refer the doc [Working with extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633691(v=exchg.80)) for more details on accessing extended properties from EWS.